# JQuery Mobile - Expandable Listview not working correctly after refresh if dynamically added content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having issues with a jquery mobile listview when I add the items through jquery code.

If I add the following < ul > to the page and let the "normal" page processing happen, my list appears correctly with expandable sub lists, etc.

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="Ul2" class="ui-listview-outer ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inset="true">
<li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-icon="plus">
    <h2 vid="CA175191-FA4D-4F2A-AAA7-2898971AB0F4">Parent 1</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
            <h2 vid="65E74F52-54E6-4A84-B4AC-F24E638FE559">Sub 1</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
            <h2 vid="86628CD0-87BD-4649-8899-1029AD38DD9C">Sub 2</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
            <h2 vid="12C6A457-EEA1-47A0-A63D-3222DF3069F2">Sub 2</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" vid="367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A">Child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-icon="plus">
    <h2 vid="864FCB4E-98A1-4C0C-9421-E89F5C5423A6">Parent 2</h2>
</li>
</ul>
```

But, if I add the same code in dynamically

```
var myData = '<li>' + ........ + '</li>';
$('ul').append(myData);
```

and then run

```
$('ul').listview("refresh")
```

The list behaves differently.

1. The list physically displays differently on the page
2. When clicking on the "Parent 1", rather than expanding to show "Sub 1", it redirects the page to show a list with "Sub 1" as a header to the list, and 4 empty list items.

I'm confused as to what to try next.  Is there ANOTHER step I should take to refresh my list.  OR have I added some incorrect classes to the elements.

Here is the JSON I'm trying to display in the lists and sub lists, it's a bit cut-down so there are probably extra square brackets that appear not to be necessary - It starts as XML and is converted to JSON from the server-side before being returned to the client :

```
{
    "parents":
    {
        "parent":
        [{
            "parName": "Parent 1", "parID": "CA175191-FA4D-4F2A-AAA7-2898971AB0F4",
            "subs":
            {
                "sub":
                [{
                    "group_Name": "Sub 1", "group_ID": "65E74F52-54E6-4A84-B4AC-F24E638FE559",
                    "children":
                    {
                        "child":
                        [
                        { "vID": "367806EA-493F-45BB-BAC9-DF11E946E21A", "dispName": "Child 1" },
                        { "vID": "4DE698E0-E395-4FF9-9F74-E8679B992AED", "dispName": "Child 2" },
                        { "vID": "747EF952-C565-41C6-AF96-B7192AD3599A", "dispName": "Child 3" },
                        { "vID": "5BDD8BD5-27E3-4E71-9C02-7E41CADF327E", "dispName": "Child 4" }
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you use a listview inside a listview, they get converted into a nested listview. Nested listviews redirect to new page with content of sub-listview.

Comment: @Omar that makes sense, but why would it behave differently depending on whether it's added dynamically and refreshed, or just added initially in the html?
How can I make the dynamically added elements display and act the same?

Comment: I guess it depends on when you _enhance_ the elements. Could provide a sample JSON of your data?

Comment: @Omar I've added in the JSON example.  If there is a simple way to say dump the json object into the list and somehow have the framework/library handle it, that would be even better.  Something like this would be awesome : $('ul').loadJSON(jsonObj);

Comment: `Ul2` is also dynamic or static?

Comment: The way I got "Ul2" is I paused js execution and take the resulting html code and paste it onto my page.  Visual Studio auto renamed it to that so that the html element id's didn't clash.  The LI elements in that html code is exactly what my js function was appending to the original UL element, the dynamic one.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64487/discussion-between-omar-and-ads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that upgrading my JQM version to 1.4.5 and using `.enhanceWithin()` on the parent div rather than using `.listview("refresh")` solved my issue.

Thanks @Omar for pointing me in the right direction.